# How to pass byte arrays by reference in C# (to C code in a DLL)

Tags: c#, c, arrays, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass an I/O array of bytes
from C# to a C routine (which is in a DLL).  By "I/O" I mean that
the C# code wants to setup the data in the array, call the C routine,
and see modified data in the array when it comes back.
(Using Visual Studio 2008 on Win XP.)

I'd been told by various sources that arrays in C# were always
passed by reference ... so I hoped "char [] buf" would be
the solution.  It doesn't appear to be ... it seems like C# is
doing sneaky stuff behind my back (e.g., passing a copy of the data?).

(I've searched, but haven't found a useful "C# for C programmers" that
discusses parameter passing from C# to C :)

(If I could determine how to get the address of 'stemp' below *within C#*,
I could display it before the call to the C code and after it ...
and display the incoming address within the C code.)

Here's the main C# code:

```
[DllImport("c:/home/sieler/source/upshift.dll")]
internal static extern void ss_upshift1 (char [] buf, Int32 bytes);

static void Main(string[] args)
   {

   char [] stemp = new char [132];
   string s;

   s = "Testing\n\0";
   stemp = s.ToCharArray ();
   Console.WriteLine (stemp);  // I see "Testing" on console window

   ss_upshift1 (stemp, 7);     // Inside the C routine, I see "Testing\n" and
                               // I change it to "TESTING\n"

   Console.WriteLine (stemp);  // I see "Testing", which is WRONG!
```

When I come back from ss_upshift1, 'stemp' still has the unchanged
data (even though I *know* the data was modified...I can print 'stemp'
from inside the C "ss_upshift1" routine before and after the
upshifting!).

If I make the 'buf' parameter be 'out', then (a) I see a buffer of nulls
in the C code (as if C# was saying "I'll allocate you a fresh buffer as
a copy of 'stemp', and zero the buffer, and pass its address),
and if I put data into the buffer within C, the C# code traps when I
come back from ss_upshift1.  (If I don't put in data in C, no trap
(and no useful data, of course :).)

C# doesn't appear to have an "io" tag (as opposed to 'out' or 'ref').

If I make the 'buf' parameter be 'ref', then C# sends the address of the 
address of the buffer (e.g., like char **buf in C).  The C code can
dereference it, find the data ... but if the data is changed, the
calling C# code does *NOT* see the changed data!

So, to ask a formal question: how do I pass an array of byte data from
C# to C, and get modified data back?

thanks,
Stan

Comment: Did you even tried to google: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pass+a+string+from+C%23+to+C+dll at least four answers on the first page!

Comment: What is the signature of ss_upshift1 in the C code?

Comment: alk...sheesh.  First, I said I searched.  Second, I did not mention strings for a darn good reason.  (I've only been programming for 45+ years, but I have learned that 'string' doesn't always mean 'array of char' :)  Third, not one of the first five hits on your search discusses byte arrays *or* I/O parameters (that is a parameter that is used to pass data into a function *and* get data back), and, in short, none of them deal with getting data back from the C routine.  (Tip: "const char *s" in the C code means you're not changing data.)   [more next]

Comment: [oart 2...stackoverflow refused to let me have an adequate length reply to alk :)]     Fourth, not all languages that support strings make it easy to use 8-bit data in the strings (e.g., in some languages, an ASCII NUL (binary 0) terminates a string).  Fifth, politeness counts.

Comment: Szabolcs Dézsi ... not sure what you're asking, or why.  Unless you're conjecturing that some mystical authority didn't "sign" my C code, and therefore C# / VS is deliberately (and quietly) throwing away output from the C routine?  The internals of the ss_upshift routine shouldn't matter for this question.  Indeed, I should have called the routine "foo", as I don't want answers like "to upshift in C#, do this...." :)     thanks.